# Problems coming in a canvas object following the mouse pointer in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a simple rectangle which will follow my mouse pointer on canvas. But when I move the pointer over the canvas , the rectangle disappears . I implemented a time.sleep() function in between to cause a delay and see actually where does it go , and it happened to move out of the canvas.

My code :

```
pointer = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,20,20, fill = "red")

def pointer_mouse(event):
     x,y = event.x, event.y
     canvas.move(pointer, x, y)
```

Comment: What is your `bind`? Does it seem likely that the rectangle is behind the mouse pointer?

Comment: Maybe , but this rectangle is big enough to be seen (maybe).

Comment: My bind is motion

Comment: Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Ok I got it , thanks for responding btw, you have to use canvas.coords(x,y) instead of canvas.move(). Because coords will.place it to x and y place while move will add the x and y to respective axis

Comment: This code doesn't show any bindings. Please provide us with a [mcve].